Spatial filtering in ArcGIS Online dashboards
I'm developing a dashboard using ArcGIS Online. Here, I want to use spatial filter option to filter all my indicators.
Ex: If I select a region, I want to filter all indicators spatially. (not by fields)
Any ideas?

I suspect you need to look into actions. https://doc.arcgis.com/en/dashboards/latest/create-and-share/actions.htm
